# Pattern matching on bson tuples

Tags: erlang

The [`bson-erlang` module](https://github.com/TonyGen/bson-erlang) turns BSON-encoded JSON such as this:

```
{ "salutation" : "hello",
  "subject" : "world" }
```

Into an Erlang tuple like this:

```
{ salutation, <<"hello">>, subject, <<"world">> }
```

Now, the server I'm attempting to talk to can put those fields in any order, and there might be extra fields in there that I don't care about, so -- equally validly -- I might see this instead:

```
{ subject, <<"world">>, salutation, <<"hello">>, reason, <<"nice day">> }
```

Is there any way that I can specify a function pattern that extracts a particular piece of the tuple, based on the one appearing immediately before it?

If I try the following, it fails with "no function clause matching..." because the arity of the tuple is wrong, and because the fields that I care about aren't in the correct place:

```
handle({ salutation, Salutation, _, _ }) -> ok.
```

Is this possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
T = { subject, <<"world">>, salutation, <<"hello">>, reason, <<"nice day">> },
L = size(T),
L1 = [{element(I,T),element(I+1,T)} || I <- lists:seq(1,L,2)].

[{subject,<<"world">>},
 {salutation,<<"hello">>},
 {reason,<<"nice day">>}]

proplists:get_value(salutation,L1).                           
<<"hello">>
```

and if you want all in 1:

```
F = fun(Key,Tup) -> proplists:get_value(Key,[{element(I,Tup),element(I+1,Tup)} || I <- lists:seq(1,size(Tup),2)]) end.

F(reason,T).
<<"nice day">>
F(foo,T).
undefined
```

Comment: I can already do that with `bson:at`, though this is useful, thanks. I was wondering whether I could do it with a pattern?

Comment: I think it is not possible to match an internal elements of a tupple if you don't know its length in advance and don't want to transform it to other type like a list.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no pattern that successfully matches values from a variable-length structure after a prefix of an unknown length**. This is true for tuples, lists and binaries. Indeed, such a pattern would require to recurse through the structure.

A common approach for a list is to recurse by splitting head and tail, something typical of functional languages.

```
f_list([salutation, Salutation | _]) -> {value, Salutation};
f_list([_Key, _Value | Tail]) -> f_list(Tail);
f_list([]) -> false.
```

Please note that this function may fail if the list contains an odd number of elements.

The same approach is possible with tuples, but **you need [guards](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80116) instead of matching patterns** as there is no pattern to extract the equivalent of the tail of the tuple. Indeed, tuples are not linked lists but structures with a O(1) access to their elements (and their size).

```
f_tuple(Tuple) -> f_tuple0(Tuple, 1).

f_tuple0(Tuple, N) when element(N, Tuple) =:= salutation ->
    {value, element(N + 1, Tuple)};
f_tuple0(Tuple, N) when tuple_size(Tuple) > N -> f_tuple0(Tuple, N + 2);
f_tuple0(_Tuple, _N) -> false.
```

Likewise, this function may fail if the tuple contains an odd number of elements.

Based on elements in the question, the advantage of guards over `bson:at/2` is unclear, though.